# .NET features ORM, DAO, ActiveRecord (CRUD)

Tags: .net, activerecord, orm, crud, dao

I've recently started working with .NET and I need to develop a medium sized web application.

In the past I developed web apps using PHP and Yii and Yii helped me a lot with it's features regarding database manipulation and mappings.

I would like to have the [features from Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.overview) (checking the entire section database section would be great) also in my .NET project. I made some research in finding something useful and I found a lot of things but they were outdated (2010, 2011) and with the newest version of .NET many things may have changed.

In a few words, I want an easy way to develop my web app project using the patterns from the title: ORM, DAO, ActiveRecord (CRUD) and I don't know where to start or what should I choose and in which direction should I go.

From my research, I found useful `NHibernate` and `Castle ActiveRecord` based on NHibernate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLOSURE EDIT** : I joined this compagny since April 2014 mostly because of the quality of their product.

I think you could looked into CodeFluent Entities which I used in several projects, and which is free for personal use : http://www.softfluent.com/codefluententities

Comment: I was not a SoftFluentee before. I joined them because of the quality of their product, so I think my answer is perfectly valid. I will add a disclosure to avoid this kind of interpretation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I continued my research and it seems that MVC Project Template from Visual Studio 2013 (even express edition) and Entity Framework from .NET would solve my problems.

Comment: I think you should have a look at http://www.softfluent.com/docs/codefluent/codefluent-entities-entity-framework.pdf if you didn't start too much the development yet ;)